# Customizing the numbers used by DisplayFormulaNumbered cells

Tags: formatting, stylesheet

[image]

I was typesetting some formulas and I encountered a formula number marked with a prime.

I am using the `DisplayFormulaNumbered` cell style`. How can I add a cell with numbered with $7'$? Here is an excerpt from one of my notebooks marked to show how I want a formula numbered.

[image]

Comment: That isn't going to work as an *automatic* cell counter. You would need to set 4' manually or perhaps create a separate style

Comment: Are you aware that a `DisplayFormulaNumbered` cell doesn't contain any reference to the number it displays? That makes  it a bit hard to get control over the displayed number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have created a new style to implement this. The first screen grab is the finished product:

[image]

Here is a pic with the underlying expression shown. Note the new style `"DisplayFormulaNumberedPrimed"`:

[image]

The new style was added to the private stylesheet for this notebook:

[image]

The underlying box code for this style is:

```
Cell[StyleData["DisplayFormulaNumberedPrimed", StyleDefinitions>StyleData["DisplayFormulaNumbered"]],
CellFrameLabels->{{None, 
    Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"(",SuperscriptBox[ CounterBox["DisplayFormulaNumbered"], \[Prime]], ")"}]],
    FontFamily->"Times",FontSize->Inherited]], 
     "DisplayFormulaEquationNumber"]}, {None, None}},
CounterIncrements->""
]
```

Note that aesthetically you will probably want to tweek this because the parenthesis size rescale due to the prime.

**Edit**

This is a bit cleaner:

```
Cell[StyleData["DisplayFormulaNumberedPrimed", StyleDefinitions->StyleData["DisplayFormulaNumbered"]],
CellFrameLabels->{{None, 
Cell[TextData[{
 Cell[BoxData[
  RowBox[{Cell["("], "\[NegativeThinSpace]", 
   SuperscriptBox[ CounterBox["DisplayFormulaNumbered"], \[Prime]], "\[NegativeThinSpace]",Cell[")"]}]],FontFamily->"Times",FontSize->Inherited]
}], "DisplayFormulaEquationNumber"]}, {None, None}},
CounterIncrements->""
]
```

[image]

Note that the way this works is that `CounterIncrements->""` prevents any incremental increase in the counter -- since you want to use the same counter number as the `"DisplayFormulaNumbered"` cell immediately prior to the primed number.